# Regex: txt vs tx?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use RegEx to validate wildcards, and I am running into trouble differentiating between \somefile.tx? and \somefile.txt.
I have gotten this far

```
\\[^\\]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$
```

which will catch tx?, but it also catches txt. How do I revise this to catch "three alphanumeric or question mark, and one at least MUST be a question mark"

Currently I am using a multiple match option Regex

```
\\\*|\\\*\.\*$|\\.\.\*$|\*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$|\\[^\\]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$|\\[^\\]*\.\*$
```

and I am starting to think I should move this to a switch so when I match either .txt or .tx? or the like, I can then simple test for a ? anywhere in the extension to flag it as a valid wildcard. But if there is a way to refine the single RegEx that is preferable I suspect.

Comment: Does the ? have to be the 3rd of the 3 characters, or can it be in any position? In other words, do you also want to match: ?xt and t?t

Comment: Indeed, the ? can be any one or more of the three characters, but unless at least one is a ? it isn't a valid wildcard.

Comment: does powershell support `look-aheads`?

Comment: @Fallenhero it does. `(?=text-to-find-ahead)`

Comment: No, ? is a literal. I want to catch all valid windows path wildcards, so \\*.* and \\any text.??? and \\any text.tx? and \\any text.?xt and \\* at the end of the string are all valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your scenario, this should work:

You identified this regex as not quite sufficient:

```
\\[^\\]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$
```

If you replace this part:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$
```

With this:

```
(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]\?[a-zA-Z0-9\?]|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{2}\?)$
```

I believe you will get the results you want.

Note that `\?` matches a question mark (without the \ in front of the question mark, ? matches one of *any* character

Breaking it down:

`\?[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{2}` matches ? followed by 2 alpha-numeric or ?

`[a-zA-Z0-9\?]\?[a-zA-Z0-9\?]` matches one alpha-numeric or ?, followed by ?, followed by one alpha-numeric or ?

`[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{2}\?` matches 2 alpha-numeric or ?, followed by ?

In this context, each of the 3 expressions (above) are "sub-expressions". The sub-expressions inside of the parenthesis, and separated by "|", means pick one of the 3 sub-expressions. (The "|" is an "or" operator)

Comment: I think I am missing something. Given a full string of
'\\\*|\\\*\.\*$|\\.\.\*$|\*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$|\\[^\\]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$|\\[^\\]*\.\*$' which matches some other conditions too, what should I be replacing to add you approach to the next to the last option?

Comment: OK, I have it working with mangotang's solution. Now I'll flesh out the rest of my code, then come back and work with briantist's solution and see what more I can learn on the RegEx front!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
\\[^\\]*\.(?=.*?\?.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?]{3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qrCEq5-zD2lQohTY)

I added this part:

```
(?=.*?\?.*?)
```

Right between your literal dot `.` and the part that matches the extension. The rest of your regex has been unmodified.

It's a positive look-ahead, which is a zero-width match (doesn't become part of the match).

It says "if followed by any number of characters (non-greedy), followed by a literal `?`, followed by any number of characters (non-greedy)."

It's basically just looking to make sure a question mark is somewhere ahead. If there is one, the match can proceed, the part you had will capture the extension.